# How to fix: Class PFLogger is implemented in both / Class PFFile is implemented in both

Tags: xcode, parse-platform, parse-server

When I run my Workspace on the simulator I get the message
"Class PFFile/ PFLogger is implemented in both (Path) and (Path). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined."

I don't know how to solve this problem. I already tried cleaning and resetting.

```
objc[7398]: Class PFFile is implemented in both
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoFoundation.framework/PhotoFoundation (0x11fdaf1b8)
and
/Users/Sven/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/20F88AC5-6C5F-4492-8324-9205B54FB32C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/8DD1D026-2D96-49E1-A485-6FCBD9899005/FitTip.app/Frameworks/Parse.framework/Parse (0x108c27408).
One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[7398]: Class PFLogger is implemented in both
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoFoundation.framework/PhotoFoundation (0x11fdaff28)
and
/Users/Sven/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/20F88AC5-6C5F-4492-8324-9205B54FB32C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/8DD1D026-2D96-49E1-A485-6FCBD9899005/FitTip.app/Frameworks/Parse.framework/Parse (0x108c279f8).
One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Answer (score 3):

## Cause

You're seeing this error because both Parse and PhotoFoundation have files named `PFFile` and `PFLogger`. In Objective-C, your program cannot have two classes that share the same class name. This is part of the reason why [Apple advocates using a three letter prefix](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html) for your own class names. Apple's own frameworks always use two letter prefixes, hence PhotoFoundation related classes have a `PF` prefix.

Unfortunately in this case, Parse also chose to use the `PF` prefix across all of the classes in the library that they built. In isolation this won't cause a problem, but when other frameworks come into the picture there's a risk of namespace collisions (which is exactly what's happening here).

## Solution

You avoid a namespace collision by simply making sure you don't use the same names. In your case, you don't own either of these classes so it's not as straightforward. Luckily this issue was already reported on the [Parse SDK GitHub page](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/1325) and the fix was implemented on the latest version of the Parse SDK (1.17.2). Parse's `PFFile` and `PFLogger` were renamed to `PFFileObject` and `PFSystemLogger` respectively.

You probably have an older version of the Parse SDK installed in your project. This can be verified by going into the root folder of the project and opening up `Podfile.lock` in any text editor. You can see what version of the library is currently installed by CocoaPods. Run `pod update Parse` and CocoaPods should update it to the latest version.

**TL;DR `pod update Parse`. If that fails: `pod repo update`, `pod install`**

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different problem. Etrecheck pointed out this problem:

Class MDSPathFilter is implemented in both `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata (0x7fff9a7d1420)`

and `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Support/mdbulkimport (0x10ad41948)`

One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

I am not proficient in this stuff, but able to follow directions if anyone has any to share. They both look too important to poke at ...